# Restrict highlighting to matching fields in Solr 5.5

Tags: solr, highlight, solr5

We are using Solr 5.5.

I would like to know if it is possible to restrict highlighting as described below.

Suppose we have this search:

```
doc_id:100 OR samples
```

which is transformed into

```
doc_id:100 OR text:samples
```

We want the highlighting to of "100" to be restricted to the doc_id field, and "samples" to be highlighted in the document_* fields copied to the text field.

With basic highlighting enabled we get "100" highlighted in *any* field (per the documentation), e.g. `hl=true&hl.fl=*`

```
  "highlighting": { 
    "2918": { 
      "document_content": [ 
        " \t\t <em>100</em> \t\t 90 \t\t 95 \t\t 90 \t\t 95 \t\t 80 \t\t 85 \t\t 85 \t\t 80 \t\t 90.42 \t\t 66.67 \t\t 90.4166666667 \t\t \t\t 1085" 
      ], 
      "doc_id": [ 
        "<em>100</em>" 
      ] 
    }, 
    "4413": { 
      "document_title": [ 
        "Purchased <em>samples</em>" 
      ], 
      "doc_id": [ 
        "<em>100</em>" 
      ], 
      "document_file_name": [ 
        "<em>Samples</em> late 2004.doc" 
      ] 
    }, 
...
```

The recommended solution is to use `hl.requireFieldMatch` but this results in only the doc_id field being highlighted. The other (document_*) fields are no longer highlighted, I guess because they don't match text, e.g. `hl=true&hl.fl=*&hl.requireFieldMatch=true`

```
 "highlighting": { 
    "2918": { 
      "doc_id": [ 
        "<em>100</em>" 
      ] 
    }, 
    "4413": { 
      "doc_id": [ 
        "<em>100</em>" 
      ] 
    }, 
    "4415": { 
      "doc_id": [ 
        "<em>100</em>" 
      ] 
    },
```

How can I get the document_* fields that are copied to the text field to be highlighted while restricting highlighting of the doc_id field to its matching query terms?

EDIT:
Perhaps, the key is to index *and store* the text field and then specify highlighting of the text and doc_id fields, i.e. change its definition to

and call `hl=true&hl.fl=text,doc_id&hl.requireFieldMatch=true`.